# Exception handling in linux

Tags: linux, exception

I am porting a Windows program on Linux. My program uses the Windows structured exception handling (SEH). Linux does not support structured exception handling, however it provides signal handling. We can override signal to develop SEH like paradigm.

Once you are able to filter the exception Windows provides three alternatives execution control flows:

1) EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : Execute handler
2) EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH : Forward the exception to next block (if not exist then to OS)
3) EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION : Continue exception from the instruction where interrupt has occured.

**How can I achieve this control flows in Linux**. In Linux once you handle the signal, program starts execution from where it has been interrupted. **How to develope continue_search and execute_handler paradigms?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

There is no easy way to do what you want here in C++. Your tools are the standard C++ exception mechanism, and `sigaction`. A `sigaction` handler can return control to where it left off. It can throw, though there has been controversy about the safety of this. Some would  say that it has to set an atomic variable and return. (The problem being that the compiler sees no possibility of a throw and so doesn't prepare for it.)

If you are working in C, you have additional complex options involving `sigsetjmp`, which is more or less goto on steroids, risks and all.

Since you haven't specified a language, or what exceptional condition you are trying to deal with, it's not practical to offer a more specific recipe.

Comment: I am using C++ language. I may be required to extract this functionality and create a shared object file. I am also afraid whether I can support signal handling within shared library. Moreover, what if the application developer has override the signal with some other handler.

Comment: I have read abou the sigaction. As you have described, it return control to where it left off. But, I also require to jump/execute particular code bypassing the existing flow (execute catch block and continue search in above blocks). Not sure how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: I have read about sigsetjmp. But, it won't be able to support when I use multiple threads and few of them receives exception at the same time.

Comment: Can't you signal a regular (pthreads) condition from inside your handler and then do the handling from a thread? You could have a signal monitoring thread dedicated to responding to the signals for immediate response. Use a proper queue in order to support concurrent events  and perhaps store metadata (time signaled, thread signaled....

Comment: Thanks for your post.I am not familiar with this regular (pthreads) condition details. Could you please point me to some APIs. I can loop up detailed information in man pages.